# Object mapping for [requestPayload] tried to parse field [requestPayload] as object, but found a concrete value

Tags: java, elasticsearch, spring-data-jpa

I am storing a JSON String as Object in elasticsearch but getting Exception below where requestPayload is as our JSON string body: 
object mapping for [requestPayload] tried to parse field [requestPayload] as object, but found a concrete value

Method as below:

```
@Override
public PushBookingNotification save(PushBookingNotification pushBookingNotification) {
    log.debug("Request to save PushBookingNotification : {}", pushBookingNotification);
    PushBookingNotification result = pushBookingNotificationRepository.save(pushBookingNotification);
    pushBookingNotificationSearchRepository.save(result);
    return result;
}
```

==== Entity as below =====

public class PushBookingNotification implements Serializable {

```
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private Long id;

@NotNull
@Column(name = "ota_hotel_id", nullable = false)
private Long otaHotelId;

@Column(name = "hotel_name")
private String hotelName;

@NotNull
@Column(name = "reference_no", nullable = false)
private String referenceNo;

@NotNull
@Type(type = "jsonb")
@Column(name = "request_payload", columnDefinition = "jsonb", nullable = false)
@Field(type = FieldType.Object)
private String requestPayload;
```

// Getter and setter methods

===== Error-log =======

```
 ERROR 10409 --- [ XNIO-2 task-11] c.atithih.cms.aop.logging.LoggingAspect  : Exception in com.atithih.cms.service.impl.PushBookingNotificationServiceImpl.save() with cause = 'NULL' and exception = 'object mapping for [requestPayload] tried to parse field [requestPayload] as object, but found a concrete value'

org.elasticsearch.index.mapper.MapperParsingException: object mapping for [requestPayload] tried to parse field [requestPayload] as object, but found a concrete value
    at org.elasticsearch.index.mapper.DocumentParser.parseObjectOrNested(DocumentParser.java:350)
    at org.elasticsearch.index.mapper.DocumentParser.parseObjectOrField(DocumentParser.java:465)
    at org.elasticsearch.index.mapper.DocumentParser.parseValue(DocumentParser.java:591)
    at org.elasticsearch.index.mapper.DocumentParser.innerParseObject(DocumentParser.java:396)
    at org.elasticsearch.index.mapper.DocumentParser.parseObjectOrNested(DocumentParser.java:373)
    at org.elasticsearch.index.mapper.DocumentParser.internalParseDocument(DocumentParser.java:93)
    at org.elasticsearch.index.mapper.DocumentParser.parseDocument(DocumentParser.java:66)
    at org.elasticsearch.index.mapper.DocumentMapper.parse(DocumentMapper.java:277)
    at org.elasticsearch.index.shard.IndexShard.prepareIndex(IndexShard.java:529)
    at org.elasticsearch.index.shard.IndexShard.prepareIndexOnPrimary(IndexShard.java:506)
    at org.elasticsearch.action.bulk.TransportShardBulkAction.prepareIndexOperationOnPrimary(TransportShardBulkAction.java:450)
    at org.elasticsearch.action.bulk.TransportShardBulkAction.executeIndexRequestOnPrimary(TransportShardBulkAction.java:458)
    at org.elasticsearch.action.bulk.TransportShardBulkAction.executeBulkItemRequest(TransportShardBulkAction.java:143)
    at org.elasticsearch.action.bulk.TransportShardBulkAction.shardOperationOnPrimary(TransportShardBulkAction.java:113)
    at org.elasticsearch.action.bulk.TransportShardBulkAction.shardOperationOnPrimary(TransportShardBulkAction.java:69)
    at org.elasticsearch.action.support.replication.TransportReplicationAction$PrimaryShardReference.perform(TransportReplicationAction.java:939)
    at org.elasticsearch.action.support.replication.TransportReplicationAction$PrimaryShardReference.perform(TransportReplicationAction.java:908)
    at org.elasticsearch.action.support.replication.ReplicationOperation.execute(ReplicationOperation.java:113)
    at org.elasticsearch.action.support.replication.TransportReplicationAction$AsyncPrimaryAction.onResponse(TransportReplicationAction.java:322)
    at org.elasticsearch.action.support.replication.TransportReplicationAction$AsyncPrimaryAction.onResponse(TransportReplicationAction.java:264)
    at org.elasticsearch.action.support.replication.TransportReplicationAction$1.onResponse(TransportReplicationAction.java:888)
    at org.elasticsearch.action.support.replication.TransportReplicationAction$1.onResponse(TransportReplicationAction.java:885)
    at org.elasticsearch.index.shard.IndexShardOperationsLock.acquire(IndexShardOperationsLock.java:147)
    at org.elasticsearch.index.shard.IndexShard.acquirePrimaryOperationLock(IndexShard.java:1657)
    at org.elasticsearch.action.support.replication.TransportReplicationAction.acquirePrimaryShardReference(TransportReplicationAction.java:897)
    at org.elasticsearch.action.support.replication.TransportReplicationAction.access$400(TransportReplicationAction.java:93)
    at org.elasticsearch.action.support.replication.TransportReplicationAction$AsyncPrimaryAction.doRun(TransportReplicationAction.java:281)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.util.concurrent.AbstractRunnable.run(AbstractRunnable.java:37)
    at org.elasticsearch.action.support.replication.TransportReplicationAction$PrimaryOperationTransportHandler.messageReceived(TransportReplicationAction.java:260)
    at org.elasticsearch.action.support.replication.TransportReplicationAction$PrimaryOperationTransportHandler.messageReceived(TransportReplicationAction.java:252)
    at org.elasticsearch.transport.RequestHandlerRegistry.processMessageReceived(RequestHandlerRegistry.java:69)
    at org.elasticsearch.transport.TransportService$7.doRun(TransportService.java:644)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.util.concurrent.ThreadContext$ContextPreservingAbstractRunnable.doRun(ThreadContext.java:638)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.util.concurrent.AbstractRunnable.run(AbstractRunnable.java:37)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Answer (score 0):

Why do you have this annotation **@Field(type = FieldType.Object)** on the field requestPayload. Maybe try to remove it and it might work.

Comment: Why are you trying to convert object to string, elasticsearch can accept object as value and it can map accordingly. Can you just try to insert object and check the mapping later. Elasticsearch can dynamically realise the mapping.   Or you can use jackson library to manually serialize object to string and then insert into elasticsearch.

Comment: We want to store a JSON object as a property Value of another JSON object in as a String ("").   Example : {"myPropery": "{"name": "abc", "age": "20"}"}